# Change Article ID From example.com/1-test To example.com/1/test

Tags: articles

I use joomla 3.4.3.

some article posted about how to remove article id, but how can I change article id from **example.com/1-test** to **example.com/1/test** ?

Thank You...

Comment: First of all update to Joomla 3.4.5 [**a high priority security update**](https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5634-joomla-3-4-5-released.html). Second your requirement for this kind of urls is one of the strangest I have ever seen and it doesn't make any sense (at least for me). What' s in your mind regarding having such urls?

Comment: ok. you can use url **www.example.com/1** instead of **www.example.com/1-test** . so i want to use short url and also give description about article with alias at the end of url. **For Example you can open this page with _http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14538_ instead of _http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14538/change-article-id-from-example-com-1-test-to-example-com-1-test_** @FFrewin

Comment: For creating short urls, look for SEF extensions like [**SH404SEF**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef) or [**JoomSEF**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/joomsef)

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to write a custom build and parse rule in a system plugin. This hooking into the content router that converts urls from /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2 to /2-article-alias and back.

See https://github.com/blackbricksoftware/multicampus for an example. A skeleton of what is needed is below.

```
class PlgSystemChangearticleurls extends JPlugin {

    public function onAfterInitialise() {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

        if ($app->isAdmin()) return;

        $router = $app->getRouter();
        $router->attachBuildRule(array($this, 'buildRule'));
        $router->attachParseRule(array($this, 'parseRule'));
    }

    public function buildRule(&$router, &$uri) {
        /* adapt display of urls */
    }

    public function parseRule(&$router, &$uri) {
        /* adapt routing of urls to corrent item */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL of a page is determined by the menu structure.

Just create a menu item of type Single Article and link to your article.
The alias of that menu item will be used in the URL structure.

Note: Joomla **3.4.3** has a **security issue**.
**Update** your website asap **to Joomla 3.4.5**, see https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5634-joomla-3-4-5-released.html

Comment: thank you. but i want to change article id no category id. like this page. _**http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14538**_ instead of _**http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14538/change-article-id-from-example-com-1-test-to-example-com-1-test**_ @pe7er